# Confused about the Alarm

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

What I want on paper is pretty simple: trigger an alarm every midnights

But being a newbie, I'm having troubles setting up such an alarm. In fact, it works okay for the most part, but it also triggers on first time activity start (after a memory wipe for instance). I understand, to some extent, that it checks if the time occured in the past or something, which doesn't really make sense to me with my poor programming knowledge.

My calendar

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

setAlarm method

```
private void setAlarm(long timeInMillis) {
// Check if Calendar is set in the past to prevent an immediate alarm */
if (mCalendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
//Add one day to the calendar (or whatever repeat interval you would like)
        mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); }

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

}
```

I think it must be pretty obvious what's wrong for veterans, but I've been stuck on this for hours. Thanks a lot if you can help me.

Comment: Use `setAlarmClock` or `setExactAndAlloeWhileIdle` and make sure you add it back for `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast and check if it's there at app start up and add it if it is not there (force stop)

Answer (score 0):

search for the broadcastreceiver. even you turn off your phone, it will
somewhat reload your pendingintent.